# Why is the term “Engineer” often misused?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I am a software developer by profession, but some people refer to me as a software engineer.

There are lots of other fields that use the term engineer; for example, civil engineer.

In my opinion, the term engineer should refer to people who work with engines in some respect.

So, why is the term engineer misused so often?

Comment: The gap between 'in my opinion' and 'misused' has been glossed over far too readily. Usage, not minority opinion, governs acceptability. A valid question here would be 'How did the sense not referring to people who work with engines in some respect develop?'

Comment: As a software developer, you shouldn't discredit your work thus.  In essence you are also a software engineer because you work with code to create a program or application. But what is a program or application without an engine to run it? In this case, the hardware engine would be the CPU and the software engine would be whatever executes the code such as a run-time or a browser, if web dev is your flavor

Answer (score 4):

The term was born misused.

The term "engineer" was originated (in Italy, IIRC) to identify people who designed "war engines" -- essentially "weapons of mass destruction" when that referred to catapults and the like, though also including fortifications and redoubts.  Then the term was split, with "civil engineer" referring to people who design roads, dams, etc for civilian use.  (Note that these people didn't use anything resembling an "engine" at the time, and "civil" meant "not military".  The term "engineer" was used because they had essentially the same foundation in mathematics and physics as the war engineers.)  Mechanical engineers were probably next -- the first time what you'd call an "engine" appeared in the mix.

Of course, since then there have been chemical, electrical, computer, industrial.  And software.  As to "software engineer" vs "programmer", some people (including myself) differentiate between the two by observing that the engineers operate "closer to the machine", and deal with problems which often require engineering design skills.

(I'll note that, while the etymology is a little vague, it appears that the terms "engine" and "engineer" originated from Latin terms meaning, roughly, "clever".)

Answer (score 2):

Early computing devices were in fact called "Engines" and were more mechanical in nature:

- [Difference Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine): (1819) "A difference engine is an automatic mechanical calculator designed to tabulate polynomial functions"
- [Analytical Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine) (1837): "The Analytical Engine was a proposed mechanical general-purpose computer designed by English mathematician and computer pioneer Charles Babbage."

The term "engine" is as at least old as the term "computer" when used to describe machines that compute. So your premise that people who work with computers aren't working with engines is faulty.

Comment: But "engineer" goes back much further than that: https://www.etymonline.com/word/engineer